# Last Key in Python Dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am having difficulty figuring out what the syntax would be for the last key in a Python dictionary. I know that for a Python list, one may say this to denote the last:

```
list[-1]
```

I also know that one can get a list of the keys of a dictionary as follows:

```
dict.keys()
```

However, when I attempt to use the logical following code, it doesn't work:

```
dict.keys(-1)
```

It says that keys can't take any arguments and 1 is given. If keys can't take arguments, then how can I denote that I want the last key in the list?

I am operating under the assumption that Python dictionaries are ordered in the order in which items are added to the dictionary with most recent item last. For this reason, I would like to access the last key in the dictionary.

I am now told that the dictionary keys are not in order based on when they were added. How then would I be able to choose the most recently added key?

Comment: There's no such thing as the "last" key in a dictionary any more than there is a "first" key.

Comment: Why do you want the last key? Python dictionaries aren't ordered.

Comment: `list(-1)` is not how you get the last element in a list... That will give you an error (you are attempting to call a list). I think you meant `list[-1]`.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

If insertion order matters, take a look at [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

> An OrderedDict is a dict that remembers the order that keys were first inserted. If a new entry overwrites an existing entry, the original insertion position is left unchanged. Deleting an entry and reinserting it will move it to the end.

---

```
In [1]: from collections import OrderedDict

In [2]: od = OrderedDict(zip('bar','foo'))

In [3]: od
Out[3]: OrderedDict([('b', 'f'), ('a', 'o'), ('r', 'o')])

In [4]: od.keys()[-1]
Out[4]: 'r'

In [5]: od.popitem() # also removes the last item
Out[5]: ('r', 'o')
```

#### Update:

An OrderedDict is no longer necessary as dictionary keys are officially ordered in insertion order as of Python 3.7 (unofficially in 3.6).

For these recent Python versions, you can instead just use `list(my_dict)[-1]` or `list(my_dict.keys())[-1]`.

Comment: I get `TypeError: 'odict_keys' object does not support indexing` when executing `od.keys()[-1]`. Using Python 3.6.1.

Comment: for `python 3` use `list(od.keys())[-1]`

Answer (score 134):

It seems like you want to do that:

```
dict.keys()[-1]
```

`dict.keys()` returns a list of your dictionary's keys. Once you got the list, the -1 index allows you getting the last element of a list.

Since a dictionary is unordered*, it's doesn't make sense to get the last key of your dictionary.

Perhaps you want to sort them before. It would look like that:

```
sorted(dict.keys())[-1]
```

Note:

In Python 3, the code is

```
list(dict)[-1]
```

#### *Update:

This is no longer the case. Dictionary keys are officially ordered as of Python 3.7 (and unofficially in 3.6).

Comment: Just a comment on dict.keys()[-1] This works in Python 2.7*, but not in Python 3.  Python 3 will error: TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing

Comment: In Python3 it worked for me with: `list(dict.keys())[-1]`

Comment: It's worth noting that dictionary keys are officially ordered as of Python 3.7 (and unofficially in 3.6).

Comment: @abe You can actually shorten it further: `[*dict.keys()][-1]`

Comment: this solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 35):

Since python 3.7 dict always ordered(insert order),

since python 3.8 `keys()`, `values()` and `items()` of dict returns: view that can be `reversed`:

to **get last key**:

```
next(reversed(my_dict.keys()))
```

the same apply for `values()` and `items()`

**PS**, to **get first key** use:
`next(iter(my_dict.keys()))`

Comment: I found this to be significantly faster. E.g. 5.7 sec vs. 0.19 sec for a `range(1000)` with default `timeit`

Comment: Kudos. This is what I was looking for. list(dict.values())[-1] is shooting yourself in the foot with worst performance! If I wanted to do that I would just use a list in the beginning instead of a dict.

Comment: Correct solution. This is constant time (& memory) whatever the size of the dict because it uses generators instead of creating a temporary list.

Comment: `reversed(d)` This is a shortcut for `reversed(d.keys())` => `next(reversed(my_dict.keys()))` => `next(reversed(my_dict))` & `next(iter(my_dict.keys()))` => `next(iter(my_dict))`

Answer (score 17):

In python 3.6 I got the value of last key from the following code

```
list(dict.keys())[-1]
```

Comment: Don't do this in Python 2.X and older versions of Python 3.X!!

Comment: or `list(dict)[-1]`

Answer (score 15):

It doesn't make sense to ask for the "last" key in a dictionary, because dictionary keys are *unordered*. You can get the list of keys and get the last one if you like, but that's not in any sense the "last key in a dictionary".

Comment: Well the dictionary is automatically going to be in the order in which it is edited so in order to access the most recent key, I need to access the last one or most recently added.

Comment: No, absolutely not! The dictionary is **not** going to be the order in which you edited it. It is an *arbitrary* order, depending on the hash value of the key.

Comment: Updated question to compensate for previous lack of knowledge.

Comment: @cbbcbail You edit asks *"How then would I be able to choose the most recently added key?"* The answer remains that you can't - that information simply isn't stored in a `dict`. You need to use another data structure (an `OrderedDict`, for example), or simply manually keep a variable around with the last added value.

Comment: Thanks, Ordered dict it is then! Ill delete my question.

Comment: This answer is obsolete since Python 3.7 Now keys are ordered in insertion order.

Answer (score 8):

```
sorted(dict.keys())[-1]
```

Otherwise, the `keys` is just an unordered list, and the "last one" is meaningless, and even can be different on various python versions.

Maybe you want to look into [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: Just a pity he does not support the "string"

Answer (score 5):

There are absolutely very good reason to want the last key of an OrderedDict.  I use an ordered dict to list my users when I edit them. I am using AJAX calls to update user permissions and to add new users. Since the AJAX fires when a permission is checked, I want my new user to stay in the same position in the displayed list (last) for convenience until I reload the page. Each time the script runs, it re-orders the user dictionary.

That's all good, why need the last entry?  So that when I'm writing unit tests for my software, I would like to confirm that the user remains in the last position until the page is reloaded.

```
dict.keys()[-1]
```

Performs this function perfectly (Python 2.7).

Answer (score 1):

You can do a function like this:

```
def getLastItem(dictionary):
    last_keyval = dictionary.popitem()
    dictionary.update({last_keyval[0]:last_keyval[1]})
    return {last_keyval[0]:last_keyval[1]}
```

This not change the original dictionary!
This happen because the popitem() function returns a tuple and we can utilize this for us favor!!

Answer (score 1):

There's a definite need to get the last element of a dictionary, for example to confirm whether the latest element has been appended to the dictionary object or not.

We need to convert the dictionary keys to a list object, and use an index of -1 to print out the last element.

```
mydict = {'John':'apple','Mat':'orange','Jane':'guava','Kim':'apple','Kate': 'grapes'}

mydict.keys()
```

> output: dict_keys(['John', 'Mat', 'Jane', 'Kim', 'Kate'])

```
list(mydict.keys())
```

> output: ['John', 'Mat', 'Jane', 'Kim', 'Kate']

```
list(mydict.keys())[-1]
```

> output: 'Kate'

Answer (score 0):

this will return last element of dictionary:

```py
dictObj[len(dictObj.keys()) - 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to ise `last_key, last_val = my_dict.popitem()`.

> popitem()
> Remove and return a (key, value) pair from the dictionary. Pairs are returned in LIFO order.
>
> popitem() is useful to destructively iterate over a dictionary, as often used in set algorithms. If the dictionary is empty, calling popitem() raises a KeyError.
>
> Changed in version 3.7: LIFO order is now guaranteed. In prior versions, popitem() would return an arbitrary key/value pair.

Then, insert the tuple again before returning `last_key`. Perhaps someday there will be a `peekitem()` function.

Comment: That's what [this answer from 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54487107/5459839) suggested.

Comment: @trincot This answer depends on the LIFO order, which was guaranteed Python 3.7 onwards. Python 3.7 was released in 2018, so, in early 2019, lot of projects might not have been using it. Failing to mention this makes the other answer incomplete.

Answer (score -1):

```
#to find last key:

dict = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4}
print(dict)

res = list(dict.key())[-1]
print(res)

#to find last value:

dict = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4}
print(dict)

res = list(dict.values())[-1]
print(res)
```

Answer (score -1):

To find the last key of dictionary, use for loops with key , pass the loop and print the key,

```
#print last key 
d1={"one":"first","two":"second","three":"third"}
for key in d1.keys():pass
print(key)
```

Comment: There are **twelve existing answers** to this question, including a top-voted answer with nearly **one hundred votes**. Are you _certain_ your solution hasn't already been given? If not, why do you believe your approach improves upon the existing proposals, which have been validated by the community? Offering an explanation is _always_ useful on Stack Overflow, but it's _especially_ important where the question has been resolved to the satisfaction of both the OP and the community. Help readers out by explaining what your answer does different and when it might be preferred.

Answer (score -5):

yes there is : `len(data)-1`.

For the first element it´s : 0

Comment: That's a guess of the key, not an explicit method